# Users unable to access Azure b2c Tenant

Tags: azure

I have set up an Azure B2C Tenant and have users with "owner" roles assigned.
I can see the users and the "owner" roles under Access Control/Role Assignments for the B2C.
When any of the "owner" users click on the B2C settings they get the following error:
"User authorization failed. You must have access to xxxxxxxxxxx".

Have I missed something in assigning roles or is something to do with the B2C likely misconfigured?

Answer (score 0):

Resolved, although the users were assigned to the B2C, they did not have user accounts within the B2C.
Once they were added as users to the B2C with Global Admin role they gained full access.